# Threaded comments and backboneJS

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, mongoose, express

Currently, I am implementing a blog application with nodejs/expressjs and
mongoDB (+mongoose) as a database. It works fine so far but now I am trying
to implement nested/threaded comments.

As I read about the different ways how to store such comments in 
mongoDB I will store each comment in a separate document to retain
flexiblity.

In contrast to store all comments embedded in a thread I will retrieve
my comments in a unordered form from the DB with references to each parent...
Materialized paths would be an alternative but then, indexing can be problematic
due to their length.

I am planning to to the actual sorting client side when rendering
the comments - a good idea?

I read about backboneJS (relational) and ask myself if 
this is a suitable tool that can help to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes storing the comments as separate documents in Mongo would be fine. Keyed lookups are generally fast in Mongo so maintaining a separate normalized structure of Threads and Comments should work.

```
# Create thread:
db.threads.insert({ id: 123, name: "My thread title..." })

# Add comment:
db.comments.insert({ id: 1, threadId: 123, text: "My comment text..." })

# Find comments in thread by order of insertion (assuming ids are sequential):
db.comments.find({ threadId: 123 }).sort({ id: 1 })
```

Backbone is a good framework if you're building a single page app. Additionally I'd suggest looking at [Backbone Marionette](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette). It's an extension that makes a lot of cool things possible (good documentation too).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the useful tipps.

Although you helped I am not completely sure where to put the logic.

Sorting in mongo:
Great for stuff of a single thread with comments but imagine there are lots of comments with different indentation. Sorting for time destroys with the actual threaded ordering.

In Jade:
Bad because "long" running, CPU intensive stuff.

Client side: lots of logic necessary beyond simple rendering the comments.

I am looking for a way to do as much as possible on the Mongo side while preserving the actual ordering of the comments.

Comment: If i remember correctly, Mongo stores collections in insertion order so if you issue a `find()` then you should be able to use it as is (i.e. the sort order will be insertion order which would be chronological).

Comment: If you want to do the sorting on the client side, `Backbone.Collection` in combination with `Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView` makes it very easy to do so based on a custom sorting function.